# Match split words from input field with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field value that gets split.

```
<input type="text" id="findW" value="command prompt" />

const txtValue = document
  .getElementById("findW")
  .value.replace(/[.*+?^${ }()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

const r2 = txtValue.split(" ");
console.log(`R2 with split looks like: ${r2}`);
```

Every word resulted from splitting must be checked if appears in some elements in order to display them. I did it using jQuery but I would like to use vanilla JS.

```
let searchInElements = `.some-classes-to-search`;

//How can be rewritten in JS this jQuery below?
$(searchInElements).each(function (i, el) {
  if ($(this).text().match(r2)) {
    showElement(el);
  }
});
```

Function used to display elements with the words from input:

```
function showElement(el) {
  el.closest("#idOfEl")
    ? (el.closest("#idOfEl").style.display = "block")
    : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not all that different really.

```
let searchInElements = `.some-classes-to-search`;

// Vanilla
document.querySelectorAll(searchInElements).forEach(el => {
  if (el.innerText.trim().match(r2)) showElement(el);
})

function showElement(el) {
  if (parent = el.closest("#idOfEl")) parent.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and time